# Getting 404 error while redirecting from third party website to localhost

Tags: angularjs, redirect, routes

**I'm using Angular for front end and my route works perfectly in my local but when the third party website is redirecting to my localhost page i'm getting 404 error not found. What can be the issue ? Also i  have shared the error image that i'm getting while redirecting from third party website. Anyone help me out of this.**

[image]

Comment: Please share How you solve this issue? i am also getting same in react routing

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the routing to your site is using a /POST to route you there. In order to view a front end webpage the browser uses a /GET. Since there is not a response to the /POST your browser displays a 404 error.

Comment: how can i fix it ?